# Can't write details extracted from DICOM file to csv file

Tags: python, csv, dicom, pydicom

I am not able to write the details extracted from a DICOM file to a CSV file. Here's the code which I have used -

```
import pydicom
import os
import pandas as pd
import csv 
import glob 

data_dir= 'C:\\Users\\dmgop\\Personal\\TE Project - Pneumonia\\stage_1_test_images_dicom' 
patients= os.listdir(data_dir)
myFile= open('patientdata.csv','w')
for image in patients:
    lung = pydicom.dcmread(os.path.join(data_dir, image))
    print (lung)
    writer = csv.writer(myFile)
    writer.writerows(lung)
    break
```

The error which is coming up is as follows -

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\dmgop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pydicom-1.2.0rc1-py3.6.egg\pydicom\dataelem.py",
>   line 344, in **getitem**
>       return self.value[key] TypeError: 'PersonName3' object does not support
>  indexing
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\dmgop\Personal\TE
>  
>   Project - Pneumonia\detail_extraction.py", line 14, in 
>        writer.writerows(lung)   File
>  "C:\Users\dmgop\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pydicom-1.2.0rc1-py3.6.egg\pydicom\dataelem.py",
>   line 346, in **getitem**
>       raise TypeError("DataElement value is unscriptable " TypeError: DataElement value is unscriptable (not a Sequence)

Comment: Can you provide `patientdata.csv` file?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the "break" statement in your for loop means you only want the info of the first image, try:

```
import pydicom
import os
import csv 

data_dir = 'C:\\Users\\dmgop\\Personal\\TE Project-Pneumonia\\stage_1_test_images_dicom' 
patients = os.listdir(data_dir)
with open('file.csv','w') as myfile:
    writer = csv.writer(myFile)
    # patients[0] means get the first filename, no need for the for loop
    lung = pydicom.dcmread(os.path.join(data_dir, patients[0]))
    print(lung.formatted_lines)
    # pay attention to the function_call --> formatted_lines()
    writer.writerows(lung.formatted_lines())
```

Have a look at the [Pydicom docs for FileDataset](https://pydicom.github.io/pydicom/stable/api_ref.html#pydicom.dataset.FileDataset) which is the return type for the dcmread method.
Should you want to write the data for all files in the directory, try the following:

```
import pydicom
import os
import csv 

data_dir = 'C:\\Users\\dmgop\\Personal\\TE Project-Pneumonia\\stage_1_test_images_dicom' 
patients = os.listdir(data_dir)
with open('file.csv','w') as myfile:
    writer = csv.writer(myfile)
    for patient in patients:
        if patient.lower().endswith('.dcm'):
            lung = pd.dcmread(os.path.join(data_dir, patient))
            writer.writerows(lung.formatted_lines())
```

Also have a look at the last part of [this paragraph](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) on the use of 'with open() as'